# How to put a disclosure triangle's title to the right of the triangle?

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder

In [the HIG's example](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/applehiguidelines/XHIGControls/XHIGControls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000359-TPXREF141) of how to use disclosure triangles, it shows a label directly to the right of the triangle.

However, when I throw one of these onto my view in Interface Builder, the text is *centered on top of* the triangle.  I've searched the NSButton API docs, and poked at everything I can find in IB, but nothing I try will put the text to the right of the triangle.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What I generally do is use 2 buttons: one disclosure button and another button for the label:

[image]

While you can use a text field for the label, I prefer using a button and setting the button to call `performClick:` on the disclosure triangle. This makes for a much larger target area to be able to click on than a tiny triangle. (Users with trackpads will thank you).

To set up the button, change it so it looks like this:

[image]

Then set its action:

[image]

I'm not sure if there's an actual way to get the button to show both properly (without subclassing I mean), since I've generally just used separate items to give the effect. (I just checked and there is indeed a Carbon disclosure control that has both the triangle and the label built-in).

The Carbon control has the right idea where clicking on the label will automatically trigger the control. In some places (notably the re-written Cocoa Finder), you can see that you don't get that behavior for free (unless you use a button like I've shown). I still have an open bug on that one (rdar://6828042): BugID 6828042: **10.6 (10A335) Finder: Inspector's disclsr. triangle's text label not toggleable**". ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just using a triangle and using a separate label?

Comment: Yeah, I could do that, but clicking the label wouldn't expand the triangle.  Doing so works for radio buttons, and it should work for this, too.

Answer (score 0):

The disclosure triangle widget is drawn by the button's bezel, centered in the available space. To create a disclosure triangle button which also has a title, you just need to subclass `NSButtonCell` and make sure the bezel is restricted to the left side of the button and that the title avoids the bezel. Then add your button in IB, expand it and set your title, and set the class of the cell. Unfortunately, IB won't know how to display your subclass and will put the triangle in the middle of the button. Just make sure it's big enough.

[image: The button will not look right in IB, but don't worry.]

In Objective-C:

```
@interface TitledDisclosureTriangleButtonCell : NSButtonCell
@end

#define TRIANGLE_PADDING    15.f

@implementation TitledDisclosureTriangleButtonCell

- (NSRect)titleRectForBounds:(NSRect)theRect
{
    NSRect titleRect = [super titleRectForBounds:theRect];

    titleRect.origin.x = TRIANGLE_PADDING;
    titleRect.size.width = NSWidth(titleRect) - TRIANGLE_PADDING;

    return titleRect;
}

- (void)drawBezelWithFrame:(NSRect)frame inView:(NSView *)controlView
{
    NSRect bezelFrame = frame;
    bezelFrame.size.width = TRIANGLE_PADDING;

    [super drawBezelWithFrame:bezelFrame inView:controlView];
}

@end
```

And in Swift:

```
let TRIANGLE_PADDING: CGFloat = 15

class TitledDisclosureTriangleButtonCell: NSButtonCell
{
    override func titleRectForBounds(theRect: NSRect) -> NSRect {
        var titleRect = super.titleRectForBounds(theRect)

        titleRect.origin.x = TRIANGLE_PADDING
        titleRect.size.width = titleRect.size.width - TRIANGLE_PADDING

        return titleRect
    }

    override func drawBezelWithFrame(frame: NSRect, inView controlView: NSView) {
        var bezelFrame = frame
        bezelFrame.size.width = TRIANGLE_PADDING

        super.drawBezelWithFrame(bezelFrame, inView: controlView)
    }
}
```